# How can I prevent Windows 10 from any kind of sleep or hibernate when running python script?

Tags: windows, windows-10, python, sleep, hibernate

I'm running a python script, which takes a couple of days. But Windows 10 seems keep pausing the script after some time, i.e. when I leave for a while the program stops (screen off also), but when I come back and do whatever things, the program will resume. Although I change all the power options in Windows 10, like

"never go to sleep when plugged in"

"never turn off hard disk"

"allow hybrid sleep: off"

"never hibernate"

Extra information: Windows edition: Windows 10 pro; 64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor;

python: Python 2.7.12 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:42:13) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Comment: In the power plan, I also chose the `High performance`

Comment: Settings->power and sleep->[set the screen and sleep times to 'never']

Comment: @ssaltman, that's the first example I listed above, "never go to sleep when plugged in"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the tool [Don't Sleep](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/DontSleep) while running your python script:

> Don't Sleep is a small portable program to prevent system shutdown,
>   Standby, Hibernate, Turn Off and Restart.

[image]

This prevents all action that can interrupt your script.

Answer (score 2):

Runs a program preventing sleeping or the display turning off while the program runs. Doesn't affect the screensaver.

Using `pywin32` library you can do exactly the same.
I note that `pywin32` doesn't actually wrap this function.

For more info see docs https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate

NOTE: Do not use the constant 
`ES_USER_PRESENT` as it will always fail.

From above link

> ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED  0x00000040  Enables away mode. This value must be
>   specified with ES_CONTINUOUS. Away mode should be used only by
>   media-recording and media-distribution applications that must perform
>   critical background processing on desktop computers while the computer
>   appears to be sleeping. See Remarks.
>
> ES_CONTINUOUS 0x80000000  Informs the system that the state being set
>   should remain in effect until the next call that uses ES_CONTINUOUS
>   and one of the other state flags is cleared.
>
> ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED   0x00000002  Forces the display to be on by
>   resetting the display idle timer.
>
> ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED    0x00000001  Forces the system to be in the working
>   state by resetting the system idle timer.

**To Use**

```
KeepDisplayOn <commandline of program to run>
KeepSystemOn <commandline of program to run>
```

---

```
@Echo Off
ECHO Three files follow
ECHO PreventSleep.bat
ECHO.
ECHO This file compiles KeepDisplayOn.vb and KeepSystemOn.vb to KeepDisplayOn.exe and KeepSystemOn.exe using the system VB.NET compiler.
ECHO.
ECHO Runs a program preventing sleeping or the display turning off while the program runs
ECHO.
ECHO To Use
ECHO      KeepDisplayOn ^<commandline of program to run^>
ECHO      KeepSystemOn ^<commandline of program to run^>
ECHO.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc "%~dp0\KeepDisplayOn.vb" /out:"%~dp0\KeepDisplayOn.exe" /target:winexe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc "%~dp0\KeepSystemOn.vb" /out:"%~dp0\KeepSystemOn.exe" /target:winexe
pause
```

---

```
'KeepSystemOn.vb
imports System.Runtime.InteropServices 

Public Module MyApplication  

Public Declare UNICODE Function SetThreadExecutionState Lib "Kernel32" (ByVal esFlags as Integer) as Integer
Public Const  ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = &h40
Public Const  ES_CONTINUOUS = &h80000000
Public Const  ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = &h2
Public Const  ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = &h1
Public Const  ES_USER_PRESENT = &h4


    Public Sub Main ()
        Dim wshshell as Object
        Dim Ret as Integer
        WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Ret = SetThreadExecutionState(ES_Continuous + ES_System_Required + ES_Awaymode_Required)
        WshShell.Run(Command(), , True)
    End Sub 
End Module
```

---

```
'KeepDisplayOn.vb
imports System.Runtime.InteropServices 

Public Module MyApplication  

Public Declare UNICODE Function SetThreadExecutionState Lib "Kernel32" (ByVal esFlags as Integer) as Integer
Public Const  ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = &h40
Public Const  ES_CONTINUOUS = &h80000000
Public Const  ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = &h2
Public Const  ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = &h1
Public Const  ES_USER_PRESENT = &h4


    Public Sub Main ()
        Dim wshshell as Object
        Dim Ret as Integer
        WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Ret = SetThreadExecutionState(ES_Continuous + ES_Display_Required + ES_Awaymode_Required)
        WshShell.Run(Command(), , True)
    End Sub 
End Module
```

---

Posted to my repository as well https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2020/05/keepdisplayon-runs-program-preventing.html