# Is there a convenient way to toggle windows 10 sleep mode on and off?

Tags: windows-10, sleep

Note I am not asking how to turn on and off sleep mode (for windows 10). I am asking if there a convenient toggle such as the ones here:

[image]

or a keyboard shortcut.

The goal is to quickly toggle sleep mode off before playing a movie and turn it on once finished.

If you need clarification feel free to ask.

Comment: There is a small program you can make at https://superuser.com/questions/1203162/how-can-i-prevent-windows-10-from-any-kind-of-sleep-or-hibernate-when-running-py/1550101#1550101 that allows you to start a program and the computer won't sleep while that program runs.

Comment: Is there a way I can launch a program and close it using shortcuts? The program "Don't sleep" was mentioned in the link.

Comment: I didn't write don't sleep. I wrote KeepDisplayOn.

Comment: @Mark I was referring to this answer https://superuser.com/a/1203169/603199 not yours.

Answer (score 0):

This method is 1 more click from your given convenient example:

1. Go to "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options".
2. Click "Create a power plan".
3. Duplicate "Balanced (Recommended)" to "No Sleep" plan name

   Then set "Put the computer to sleep" as "Never".
4. "Show additional plans".
5. Put a shortcut to this finished toggle into Start Menu.

---

6. Drag "Power Options" from the address to "Desktop".
7. Rename shortcut to Remove the extra "shortcut" word.
8. Move the shortcut to "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs".